# blockmodel: convert json to .x3d

Tags: python, python-2.7

In blockmodel, is there an easy way to convert a json to a .x3d file? Is there a helper method to do this, or should I do this the manual way (loading the json and then writing it to disk)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it the manual way. Something like this will work:

```
with open(data_path("ref/073985f1c3e2f26c5be4a01073de42d3"), "r") as f:
    as_json = f.read()

blockmodel = BlockModel.from_json(as_json)
x3d = blockmodel.x3d

with open(data_path("made/x3d_ref.x3d"), "w") as f:
    f.write(x3d)
```